# How to define a variable/method in the props with redux in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I'm implementing an authentication, I have a problem with the props.

When I display the props, I don't have the props `authState` so
I got an error that I don't understand where it comes from and I can't solve it. Here's the error:

```
[21:42:10] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this$props$authState.app_started')

This error is located at:
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

App.js

```
import ... 

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.checkLogin();
  }
  _renderSplash = ()=>{
    return (
        <View>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
          <Text children='Loading...'/>
        </View>
    );
  }

  _renderRoot = (authenticated)=>{
    const Navigation = Navigation(authenticated);
    return <Navigation/>;
  }

  render() {
      console.log(this.props); // it don't show -> this.props.authState
      const {app_started, authenticated} = this.props.authState;
      const Root = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) ((app_started ? this._renderRoot(authenticated): this._renderSplash));
      return (
        <Provider store={configureStore}>
          <Root/>
        </Provider>
      );
  }

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        authState: state.authState
      }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps)=>{
  return {
    async checkLogin(){
      const isLoggin = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authenticated').catch(e => console.log(e));
      if(isLoggin){
        dispatch(actionCreator(LOGIN_SUCCESS))
      }
      dispatch(actionCreator(APP_LOADED))
    }
  }
};
```

configureStore.js

```
import {combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux';
import authStateReducer from './authStateReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authState: authStateReducer
});

const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer);
};

export default createStore(configureStore);
```

navigation.js

```
import ...
const Navigation = (authenticated)=>createStackNavigator({
    login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'login'
        }
    },
    dashboard: {
        screen: Dashboard,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'dashboard'
        }
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: authenticated ? 'dashboard': 'login'
});
export default Navigation;
```

authStateReducer.js

```
import ...
const authStateReducer = (state={app_started: false, authenticated: false} , action)=>{
    let next_state;
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            next_state = {
                ...state, authenticated: true
            };
            return next_state;
        case LOGOUT:
            next_state = {
                ...state, authenticated: false
            };
            return next_state;
        case  APP_LOADED:
            next_state = {
                ...state, app_started: true
            };
            return next_state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default authStateReducer;
```

Login.js

```
import ...
class Login extends React.PureComponent{
    _login = ()=>{
        // check the fields
        let token = 'whatever';
        this.props.authSuccess(token);
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                 <TextInput.../>
                 <TextInput...
                     onSubmitEditing={this._login}
                 />
                 <Button ... onPress={this._login}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state

};
export const actionCreator = (action, payload=null)=>{return{type: action, payload: payload}};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps)=>{
    return {
        authSuccess: (token)=>{
            AsyncStorage.multiSet([['token',token], ["login", '1']]);
            dispatch(actionCreator(LOGIN_SUCCESS))
        }
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

> I found the error, it's in `configureStore.js`

Comment: Do you have the dispatch method in `console.log(this.props)` inside App.js?

Comment: @PredragBeocanin, non, I don't have it. I tried to put the dispatch method in ```App.js``` but I have the same error

Comment: This would essentially mean that `App.js` doesn't receive redux state/props at all. Instead of connecting it, have you tried passing `this.props.state` and `this.props.dispatch` to `<Navigation />` manually?

Comment: @PredragBeocanin, I solve the error,  the error is in ```configureStore```, but now i have another error in Navigation :s

Comment: Fun day isn't it! Just post another question, if you can't crack that one yourself. Also, maybe post the solution as an answer to your own question, just so others that find this know how you solved it as well!

Comment: your `App.js` is not connected to redux store

Answer (score 0):

A lightweight React-Native Redux Boilerplate with ready to use modern technologies. This Repo provides you a good state of the art start for your next React-Native project.
Please check the link

https://github.com/Anyline/react-native-redux-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

In App.js `authState` is undefined because you need to *connect* your `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` or none of it will be available in this.props.

It should look like:

App.js

```
import...
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component { // <- get rid of export default here
...

// after mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```